# Unable to add persistent store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I'm trying to add a sqlite persistent store in `Library/Application-Support` folder as shown below:

```c
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (!_managedObjectModel)
    {
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"delete" withExtension:@"momd"];
        _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    }
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSURL *storeURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] @"delete.sqlite"];
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
                NSPersistentStore * persistentStore = [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];            
                _persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator;
            }
        }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) 
URL:file:///Users/harshithg/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D9A32558-558A-4E0E-915D-FEF25C772669/data/Containers/Data/Application/9517BBBB-E383-467E-B0E2-8960B734B239/Library/Application%20Support/delete.sqlite 
options:(null) ... 
returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(512) with userInfo dictionary { reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2";
```

I'm on iOS 13.3 and Xcode 11.3. Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: There is a problem with the url path . Check the path

Comment: NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSURL *persistentStoreURL = [documentDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"delete.sqlite"];

Comment: @Help I want to add my persistent store in Library/Application-Support folder, not in the Documents folder. I have UIFileSharingEnabled=YES, which exposes my Documents directory. I can, however, hide the .sqlite file using NSURLIsHiddenKey but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Please note that storing the sqlite file in the Library folder doesn't throw any error. Library/Application-Support seems to be causing some issue.

Comment: The Application Support folder does not exist unless you explicitly create it. Where is your code that does that?

Comment: Thanks, @matt. Creating the app support folder explicitly fixes the issue.

Comment: Cool! I'll add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application Support folder does not exist unless you explicitly create it. None of your code creates it. There's an NSFileManager method that will give you the NSApplicationSupportDirectory URL *and* create it (if it doesn't already exist) at the same time.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory?language=objc